# Can i add credit card bank account via plaid API to get access token?

Tags: plaid

I want to add credit card bank account via plaid API although i don't have account in that bank. can i do this and can any body tell me how plaid facilitate credit card accounts or credit card transactions.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, you can add an account at a bank you don't have an account at using the Sandbox test environment. Production and Development require real credentials. The rest of your question I don't quite understand.

Comment: their support team said to me remove "auth" from product array to login into cards.Currently i have initilized with "auth" when i remove "auth" from array it returns me a message "must provide at least one product" then i add "liabilities" in an array then it returns me a message "client is not authorized to access the following products: ["liabilities"]".

and i want checking, saving and credit card account so should can i initlized product array with ["auth", "liabilities"] or i have to create two seperate link.

Comment: @hu7sy are you trying to get transactions history? If so, you should initialize with the transactions product. For more info, see the transactions docs: https://plaid.com/docs/transactions/

Comment: yes i want transaction history but with transaction in product array i can't login to credit cards account.i mean to say like for some banks i have their credit card but i don't have their bank account what about those accounts ?

Comment: The transactions product supports credit card accounts. If an institution isn't showing up in Link when transactions is being used to initialize it, it's possible that institution in question doesn't happen to support transactions, or that they handle credit card online account management through a different portal.

Comment: it is showing in the list but when i enter credentials for credit card account it show me an error internal server error. @Alex can you send me your email ?

Comment: Did you find any solution?